# How to make pgRouting understand bridges and tunnels?

Tags: pgrouting, network

I have I highway that runs on a bridge over a couple of blocks in a city. How do I get pgRouting to understand that cars can't move from the small blocks on the ground up to the highway on the bridge and vise verse?

What if I manually remove the nodes/vertices? Would a driving_distance understand that the highway and the smaller block-roads underneath aren't connected?

I'm using QGIS+pgRouting+Postgresql+PostGIS

Answer (score 1):

> What if I manually remove the nodes/vertices? Would a driving_distance understand that the highway and the smaller block-roads underneath aren't connected?

Yes, it would. Driving distance (http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/driving_distance/doc/dd_driving_distance.html#pgr-driving-distance) only cares about the logical graph of connected nodes/vertices. If those are correct, overpasses and underpasses won't be an issue at all.